# How the events generation are generated in jquery-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to know how the events are generated in jquery-ui Sortable Widget?

For example. let's take the event `beforeStop`.
My questions are:

1. why does it use `this._trigger("stop", event, this._uiHash());` instead of `this.trigger("stop", event, this._uiHash());`?
2. what does `_trigger` function?

Comment: Those two are different functions `.trigger` as you know it is used to trigger any event and it is exposed as jQuery function.. where else `_trigger` seems to be an internal function used by jQuery UI and not exposed directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_trigger()` is a method inherited by all jQuery UI widgets. It calls jQuery's own [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) under the hood, but adds the following functionality:

- The event will be always be triggered on the element the widget augments (the `target` property of the event object is updated accordingly).
- The event that is triggered has the widget prefix prepended to its name (for instance, calling `_trigger("stop")` on a sortable widget will actually trigger the `sortstop` event).
- The function returns `false` if one of the registered handlers either returns `false` or calls [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault) on the event.

You can find the full implementation of `_trigger()` from lines 476 to 503 in the source code [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/widget.js#L476-503).

Comment: Just wanted to let Frederic know that the link he used is dead.

Comment: @userfuser, that's what I get for linking to github in the first place, I guess. Thanks for the heads-up :)